# Сформировать запрос в ORM Django

Tags: django

Имеем 2 модели.

```
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    еще дата публ, кол-во просмотров и т.д.

class Images(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="news/images/%m.%Y")
    news = models.ForeignKey(News, related_name='images2news')
```

Новость может иметь >= 0 картинок.
Как выбрать все новости вместе с картинками если у новости они конечно имеются?

Уже имеется неправильная реализация, которая порождает дубликаты.

```
News.objects.filter(site=1).values('pk', 'title', 'text', 'changed', "images__image").order_by("-changed").distinct()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы избежать проблемы n+1 запроса, при обратном ForeignKey (ваш случай) используйте [django-batch-select](https://github.com/lilspikey/django-batch-select)

установите его в ваше окружение:

```
pip install django-batch-select
```

а лучше добавьте в файл requariments.txt

после чего необходимо изменить менеджер objects у тех моделей, с которыми вы собираетесь его использовать. В вашем случае:

```
from batch_select.models import BatchManager

class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    ***

    objects = BatchManager()
```

И можете спокойно выбирать все новости с их картинками одним запросом:

```
news = News.objects.filter(site=1).batch_select('images')

for n in news:
    print n.title
    print n.images_all
```

Обратите внимание: теперь список объектов класса images доступен через переменную  `<related_name>_all`, можно изменить это поведение, например так: batch_select(images='images'). Возможно таким же образом выполнять сложные составные запросы и агрегации, подробнее - [в документации batch_select](https://github.com/lilspikey/django-batch-select)

Да, и, в вашей моделе неточный related_name:

```
news = models.ForeignKey(News, related_name='images2news')
```

в своём примере я использовал related_name='images'